# Calling JavaScript function from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue calling `form()` from my dropdown.

When I check the source, it shows the assist/form.js is being seen from the web-page.

I have copied and paste the `form()` the from page to the main page.

Here is an example of my Code.
main page:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="assist/form.js"></script>

<select name="field_type" onchange="form(this.value)">
```

assist/form page:

```
function form(type) {...}
```

Error I am getting following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: form is not a function at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (index.php:32)

Comment: what do you mean by "is being seen"? does the form.js file define a global `form` function? does the JS resource import work (check in network tab of inspector)?

Comment: `console.log(form)` and you will see the conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a name collision

```html
<form>
  <select onchange="console.log(form)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The console.log will show you that form will be the form you are in.

Rename your function to something else.